# Table Input Step Does not replace variables

Tags: sh, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm running the following code in the Input Step of Pentaho Kettle:

```
SELECT * FROM ${TABELA} WHERE TS_SAMPLETM BETWEEN TO_DATE('${HOJE}', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('${SEMANAPASSADA}','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

However, when I run the Job via this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/rafael/data-integration/
export HOJE=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y")
export SEMANAPASSADA=$(date -d "7 days ago" +"%d/%m/%Y")
export tabela=tabela1

sh kitchen.sh -file=/home/rafael/data-integration/Job_Oracle_MySql.kjb -param:TABELA=$TABELA -param:HOJE=$HOJE -param:SEMANAPASSADA=$SEMANAPASSADA
```

The Table Input step does not replace the variables.

Comment: To enable variable replacement, you must check the "Replace variables in script?" option at the bottom. Have you tried that?

Comment: It's checked. When I try to run with Spoon and setting the variables manually, it works perfectly.

Comment: try making ${TABELA} to '${TABELA}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is errors in your shell script, and not errors with Pentaho, or Table Input Step. If you try to insert `echo` before the `sh` on the last line you can see the command that is run:

```
echo sh kitchen.sh -file=/home/rafael/data-integration/Job_Oracle_MySql.kjb -param:TABELA=$TABELA -param:HOJE=$HOJE -param:SEMANAPASSADA=$SEMANAPASSADA
```

For me this outputs:

> sh kitchen.sh -file=/home/rafael/data-integration/Job_Oracle_MySql.kjb -param:TABELA= -param:HOJE=18/12/2015 -param:SEMANAPASSADA=

The problems in your shellscript is

1. case sensitive. Replace `$TABELA` with `$tablea`
2. for me the way of calling date is wrong, but this depends on your OS, which you have not supplied. I need to write `export SEMANAPASSADA=$(date -v -7d +"%d/%m/%Y")`

After these changes when I run the script it outputs:

> sh kitchen.sh -file=/home/rafael/data-integration/Job_Oracle_MySql.kjb -param:TABELA=tabela1 -param:HOJE=18/12/2015 -param:SEMANAPASSADA=11/12/2015

which probably is closer to what you want.